# How to show Chinese help information in my html pages?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

```
@Required
@MinLength(12)
@MaxLength(12)
@Id
@Column(length = 12)
public String id;

@Min(17)
@Max(30)
public Integer age;

@inputText(studentForm("id"), '_label -> "学号")
@inputText(studentForm("age"), '_label -> "年龄")
```

After I input error messages,such as id="1" and age=10
I get two different error messages,but one is Chinese, another is English:

1. The error for id: Minimum length is 12
2. The error for age: 最小不能小于17

How could I switch all of them to Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

Play doesn't translate messages automaticaly, so most probably you changed `conf/messages.xx` only partialy.

Find it and finish translation. Correct error's keys can be copied from: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.4/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/messages